# Reading website XML using Google App Engine & Python

Tags: python, xml, google-app-engine, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to read some xml from the world of warcraft armory (yea I'm one of those) - The url such as [this](http://eu.wowarmory.com/guild-info.xml?r=dentarg&n=penance) returns the xml in Firefox (you need to view source to see it) but not in other browsers such as Chrome (which I don't fully understand why - though that's an aside).

Anyway I have this code which works fine when I run the app locally but now I'm migrating onto Google App Engine, it isn't and I don't know why. But it seems to be failing to fetch the xml. I've used Beautiful Coup to parse the xml in the full code.

```
import urllib2,urllib
import socket
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulStoneSoup

class Object:
    def __init__(self):
        self.data = {}
        self.userAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.0; en-GB; rv:1.8.1.4) Gecko/20070515 Firefox/2.0.0.4"

    def _getXml(self):
        strFile = ""
        try:
            url = "http://eu.wowarmory.com/guild-info.xml?r=dentarg&n=penance"
            values = {}
            headers = { 'User-Agent' : self.userAgent }
            data = urllib.urlencode(values)
            socket.setdefaulttimeout(2)
            req = urllib2.Request(url, data, headers)
            response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
            strFile = response.read()
        except Exception, e:
            raise e
        finally:
            return strFile

    def getObject(self):
        soup = BeautifulStoneSoup( self._getXml() )
        return soup.guildheader["faction"]
```

Here's the main section:

```
from google.appengine.ext import webapp
from google.appengine.ext.webapp import util
from library import Object


class MainHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        test = Object().getObject()
        self.response.out.write(test)


def main():
    application = webapp.WSGIApplication([('/', MainHandler)],
                                         debug=True)
    util.run_wsgi_app(application)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I've simplified the code to try better illustrate the problem. I'd be very gratefully for any help.

Comment: You probably have an error message somewhere in the "Log" page of your admin console. Please post it here on SO.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/colmbrophy/Desktop/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/webapp/__init__.py", line 515, in __call__
  File "/Users/colmbrophy/Code/Python/Google App Engine/Test/main.py", line 47, in get
    self.response.out.write(soup.guildheader["faction"])
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is unsubscriptable

Comment: The fact that it's not finding anything is why I think it's just completely failing to grab the xml.

Comment: When I visit the link you specified I receive a redirect, no XML content.
"These aren't the Armory pages you're looking for."

Comment: If you view source the xml is there.

Comment: Perhaps it would be better to just use the new armory pages? Or is there something preventing you from doing that?

Comment: Please include the stacktrace of the exception in your original question. You should really log the response body before passing it to beautiful soup, so you can see what you're getting, too. Also, 'Object' is possibly the worst name for a class I've ever seen.

Comment: The reason the response seems different in the browser vs viewing source is this tag in the XML <?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="/_layout/guild/roster.xsl"?>.  It is instructing the browser to fetch the XSL and then process the XML through it to generate XHTML.  I had no idea anyone did this anymore!

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I've played aroun with http://shell.appspot.com/ ( FYI you can download the source and integrate it with your project for further experiments), this seems to do the trick:

```
headers = { 'User-Agent' : ""Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.0; en-GB; rv:1.8.1.4) Gecko/20070515 Firefox/2.0.0.4" }
resp = urlfetch.fetch(url="http://eu.wowarmory.com/guild-info.xml?r=dentarg&n=penance", method=urlfetch.GET, headers= headers)
print resp.content
```

Comment: thanks Piotr i'll have a look at shell and try get that working

Answer (score 0):

`urllib2.Request` does a POST when you pass the data parameter.  Is that what the server is expecting or do you need to do a GET?

Also, going to that URL now just gives a "we've moved" message.

Comment: should have mentioned that if you view source the xml is there (in Firefox at least). switching to post doesn't seem to make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

Blizzard have altered the old armory to a new site layout and format. You probably need to parse the HTML directly now.